# Vote It Up Plugin - Add ascending numbers to MostVotedAllTime Chart Function

Tags: plugins, php

The following function shows a top 10 chart of most voted posts. How would I add acceding numbers to this chart

eg

**1** - example Post1

**2** - example Post2

etc

```
function MostVotedAllTime_Widget() {
$a = SortVotes();
//Before

 ?>
<div class="JibbleChart">
<div class="title">Most Recommended Albums</div>
<?php
$rows = 0;

//Now does not include deleted posts
$i = 0;
while ($rows < get_option('voteiu_widgetcount')) {
if ($a[0][$i][0] != '') {
        $postdat = get_post($a[0][$i][0]);
    if (!empty($postdat)) {
        $rows++;

        if (round($rows / 2) == ($rows / 2)) {
            echo '<div class="fore">';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="back">';
        }
        echo get_the_term_list( $postdat->ID, 'artist', ' ', ', ', '' ); 
        echo ' - <a href="'.$postdat->guid.'" title="'.$postdat->post_title.'">'.$postdat->post_title.'</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
if ($i < count($a[0])) {
$i++;
} else {
break; //exit the loop
}
}

//End
?>

</div>
 <?php

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
function MostVotedAllTime_Widget() {
$a = SortVotes();
//Before

 ?>
<div class="JibbleChart">
<div class="title">Most Recommended Albums</div>
<?php
$rows = 0;

//Now does not include deleted posts
$i = 0;
while ($rows < get_option('voteiu_widgetcount')) {
if ($a[0][$i][0] != '') {
        $postdat = get_post($a[0][$i][0]);
    if (!empty($postdat)) {
        $rows++;

        if (round($rows / 2) == ($rows / 2)) {
            echo '<div class="fore">';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="back">';
        }
        echo get_the_term_list( $postdat->ID, 'artist', ' ', ', ', '' ); 
        echo ' - <a href="'.$postdat->guid.'" title="'.$postdat->post_title.'">'.$i.' - '.$postdat->post_title.'</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
if ($i < count($a[0])) {
$i++;
} else {
break; //exit the loop
}
}

//End
?>

</div>
 <?php

}
```